# Rails: Filtering with PG search not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

I am currently building an online library in Ruby on Rails that has books which are in different subcategories and then categories. In other words;

```
Books belong to Subcategories
Subcategories belong to Categories
```

I am using PG_search for search functionality, and here is my search method for searching books, **which works fine**:

```
pg_search_scope :search, 
                 against: [:name, :description, :author, :abstract],
                 associated_against: { category: [:name ], subcategory: [:name ] },
                 using: { tsearch: { prefix: true, dictionary: "english" } }
```

My index action of my controller looks like this:

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @books = Book.search(params[:query])   
  else  
    @books= Book.all
  end
end
```

But when I try to implement a **filter by category** in the index action of my books controller:

```
def index
  if params[:category].present? or params[:category][:id].present?
    @books = Category.find(params[:category][:id]).books.search(params[:query])   
  else  
    @books= Book.all
  end
end
```

I encounter this error:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Here is my view implementation

```
<div class="advanceSearch">
  <%= form_tag(books_path, method: :get) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], {placeholder: 'eg: Ruby', :class => 'searchForm'} %>
      <%= collection_select :category, :id, Category.all.order('name ASC'), :id, :name,{include_blank: 'Select Category'}, { :class => 'form-control'} %>
    <button type="submit">
      Search
      <%= image_tag("searchIcon.svg", :alt => "search", :class => "") %>
    </button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any form of help that will enable me **filter the books by category** and **subcategory if possible**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double if (`if if`) in your condition, and I believe you would like to use `and` instead of `or`

```
def index
  if params[:category].present? and params[:category][:id].present?
    @books = Category.find(params[:category][:id]).books.search(params[:query])   
  else  
    @books= Book.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I think that was a typo from me. I have corrected it, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Did you also fix the `and`?

Comment: Yes I used `and` instead of `or` and still got this same issue.

Comment: Could you please tell me which line throws this error? Ideally I would like to see a full stacktrace in the opening post.

Comment: Right now. It does not throw the error again, but the search feature does not search again. If I type in any book name **it just lists all the books in the library** without searching for the particular query that you entered. And even the filter feature is still like that, that is if you try filtering, it displays **No records found**. So both the search and filter features are no longer working.

Comment: **Part of the Stacktrace** - ` CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books" INNER JOIN (SELECT "books"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('english', coalesce("books"."name"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("books"."description"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("books"."author"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("books"."abstract"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce(pg_search_af6eda8ef968c5c8985fe1.pg_search_e990baea28e0dd3a28b167::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce(pg_search_adfe37fd29d60e97453eb5.pg_search_929adfe84d8a086`

Comment: I have added my view implemetation to the question, to enable you see how I am implementing my views.

Comment: You should try to isolate the issue and focus on the model first. If it is working on the model level, then you can focus on the controller and then to the view.

Comment: I am recommending to write a unit test which tests the specific use-case on the `Category` model of yours and see if that is working.